# WEKA input of predictions in 10folds CSV output

Tags: weka

I'm using WEKA Explorer to run a 10fold cross validation. I output the predictions to a CSV file. Because the 10fold approach mixes the order of the data, I do not know which specific data is correctly or incorrectly classified.
I mean, by looking at the CSV I do not know **which specific** 1 or 0 is classified as 1 or 0. Is there any way to see what is the classification result for every specific instance in test set for every fold? For example, it would be great if the CSV would record the ID of the instance being classified.

One alternative could be for me to implement the 10folds approach manually; i.e., I could create the 10 ARFF files and then run on each of them a percentage split with 90/10 (and preserve order). This solution looks pretty elaborated, effort expensive and error prone.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is not quite clear what are you asking. You have a model and you  need to classify instances ? If so why use 10-fold CV? Or you need to check your model's precision , recall etc?

Comment: Or do you need to see what is the classification result for every instance in test set for every fold?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to do the following for every fold:

```
int result = new int[testSet.numInstances()];
for (int j = 0; j < testSet.numInstances(); j++) {

    double res[j] = classifier.classifyInstance(testSet.get(j));

}
```

Now `res` array has the classification result for every Instance in test set. You can use this information as you want.
You can for example print the attributes of each instance(e.g if attributes are strings you can print them using (Before addingFilter) `testSet.get(j).stringValue(PositionOfAttributeYouWantToPrint))` followed by the classification result.

Note that if the classification result is nominal value you can print it using this:

```
testSet.classAttribute().value((int)res[j]))
```

Comment: HI xro7, thanks for your help. I never used WEKA in JAVA, I have used WEKA only via the GUI. Can you please post a more complete JAVA code assuming I use as input a file called X.arff and RandomForest as classification method? BTW, I want to print the original ID (aka order) of the instance.

Comment: i didn't reliaze that you work via GUI. Well this is not as simple as its sounds. Because i don't know what your arff file includes. It is fairly easy to follow steps from here and do it yourself http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code